# Bootstrap accordion data-parent not working with ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

You can see below an example of my error.

The first script is a simple loop to create ten collapses. In order to not overload the page, we are going to do an ajax call on the collapse's clic. The ajax call pass one parameter that is the collapse's ID. When we clic on the second collapse's level, the data-parent didn't works all the time.

I want that my second collapse's level have a normal behavior, that mean expand only one div at a time.

I'm not sure but i think that my error come from the ajax call which reload the data-parent at each clics.

Could you help me please?

```
**FRONT END SCRIPT**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <?php 

        echo "<div id='accordion'>";

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

                echo "<div class='card'>";

                    echo "<div class='card-header' id='heading-" . $i . "'>";

                        echo "<h5 class='mb-0'>";

                            echo "<button class='btn btn-link' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse-" . $i . "' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='collapse-" . $i . "''>";

                                echo "Collapsible Group Item #" . $i;

                            echo "</button>";

                        echo "</h5>";
                        
                    echo "</div>";

                    echo "<div id='collapse-" . $i . "' class='collapse' aria-labelledby='heading-" . $i . "' data-parent='#accordion'>";

                        echo "<div class='card-body'>";

                        echo "</div>";

                    echo "</div>";

                echo "</div>";
                
            }

        echo "</div>";

    ?>

    <script>

        $(function() {

            $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {

                if ($(this).is(e.target)) {   

                    var target = (this.id);

                    var id = target.replace("collapse-", "");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "test_backend.php",
                        data: {
                            id: id
                        },
                        async: false,
                        success: function(response) {
                            $('#collapse-' + id).html(response);
                        },
                        error: function(response, error) { // Info Debuggage si erreur         
                            alert("Erreur : responseText: " + response.responseText);
                        },
                    });

                }
            })

        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>


BACK END SCRIPT
    
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){

        echo "<div class='card-body'>";

            echo "<div id='accordion-1'>";

                echo "<div class='card'>";

                    echo "<div class='card-header' id='heading-1-1'>";

                    echo "<h5 class='mb-0'>";

                        echo "<button class='btn btn-link' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse-1-1' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='collapse-1-1'>";

                            echo "Collapsible Group Item #" . $_GET['id'] . " > #1";

                        echo "</button>";

                    echo "</h5>";

                    echo "</div>";

                    echo "<div id='collapse-1-1' class='collapse' aria-labelledby='heading-1-1' data-parent='#accordion-1'>";

                        echo "<div class='card-body'>";

                            echo "item " . $_GET['id'] . " > 1";
                            
                        echo "</div>";

                    echo "</div>";

                echo "</div>";  

                echo "<div class='card'>";

                    echo "<div class='card-header' id='heading-1-2'>";

                    echo "<h5 class='mb-0'>";

                        echo "<button class='btn btn-link' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse-1-2' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='collapse-1-2'>";

                            echo "Collapsible Group Item #" . $_GET['id'] . " > #2";

                        echo "</button>";

                    echo "</h5>";

                    echo "</div>";

                    echo "<div id='collapse-1-2' class='collapse' aria-labelledby='heading-1-2' data-parent='#accordion-1'>";

                        echo "<div class='card-body'>";

                            echo "item " . $_GET['id'] . " > 2";
                            
                        echo "</div>";

                    echo "</div>";

                echo "</div>";  

            echo "</div>";
        
        echo "</div>";
        
    }

?>
```

This is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13rsL.png) of my issue. The second collapse level is expand at the same time.

How to expand only one div at a time ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: have a look here everything is fine...

https://www.winlineindia.com/so/

Comment: Could you please clic on "Collapsible Group Item #1 > #1" And "Collapsible Group Item #1 > #2"  on différent Collapsible Group Item #. The data-parent dont work correctly on the second level

Comment: Visit https://www.winlineindia.com/so/ and see agin
i think its working...

Comment: It's the same behavior... look my post i have add an image of the issue.. thanks on advance for your time

Comment: You have typo in you script:
**aria-controls='collapse-" . $i . "''**
should be:
**aria-controls='collapse-" . $i . "'**

Delete one extra quote.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it doesn't change anything :s